# How to add Schema markup for a custom attribute in Magento 1.9.4

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute

I am trying to add the right Schema Markup metadata for a custom attribute in Magento 1.9.4

I tried this :

```
  <meta itemprop="gtin13" content="<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('gtin_code'); ?>" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your attribute type you can either access the data like you do for select attributes or simply get the data for text or  varchar attributes for example.

I guess in your case it is a varchar attribute so this should work:

```
$_product->getData('gtin_code');
```

If you don't get the data that way you should check that the attribute is loaded in your context (e.g. in product list by default only attributes with the option "Use in Product Listing" set to "Yes" are loaded)